# php.exe script parameters in batch file

Tags: php, windows, parameters, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a PHP script on Windows through php.exe, while passing parameters to the script. Everywhere I look, it says it should work like this:

```
php -f "path\to\my\script.php" -- -t 10 -i 5
```

The -t 10 -i 5 should be passed to script.php, where I can access them through $argv. When I type this in on the command line, everything runs as expected. When I paste the very same line in a .cmd file, the part after script.php gets treated as a seperate command. (and yes, it is a single line in the batch file)

```
C:\>php -f "path\to\my\script.php" -- -t 10 -i 5
<<<output of the php script as expected>>>
C:\>mybatch.cmd
C:\>php -f "path\to\my\script.php"
<<<output of the php script not receiving the parameters>>>
C:\>-- -t 10 -i 5
'--' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I first thought it might be a problem with the --, but even if I leave out the -- (basically passing the other parameters to php.exe instead of to the script), the same problem occurs.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, appearantly there was a linefeed after the filename of the script, but that was not visible in notepad. No idea how it got there (probably copy/paste related), but removing it fixed the problem.